# Ajax Error: "Unexpected end of input"

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am writing code to test AJAX image and data upload. However, the Ajax seems to return an error stating that the input is not valid:

> Syntax error: unexpected end of input

The script and HTML are as follows

```html
<input type="file" name="vdofile" id="file" />
<input type="text" id="name" />

<button id="send">Send</button>
```

```js
$("#send").click(function(){

    var form = new FormData();

    form.append('vdofile',$("#file").prop("files")[0]);
    form.append('name', $("#name").val());

    $.ajax({
        url: 'upload.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: form,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,

        success: function(data)
        {
            alert(data.message);
        },       
        error: function(xhr, status, error)
        {
            alert('An error occured.. ' + xhr.responseText + '..' + error );
        }

    });// ajax
}); // function
```

The test PHP is as follows:

```php
header("Content-Type: application/json");

if(isset($_FILES['vdofile']) && isset($_POST['name']))
{
    $result = array(
        'message' => 'both data and file received'
    );
}
else {
    $result = array(
        'message' => 'one of parameter missing'
    );
}
return json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your PHP is returning an empty response. `return` doesn't print anything.

```
print json_encode($result);
```

should work better.

Comment: thank you .. :) seems to work. have used `echo` instead of `print`